# "No Internet Connection" for iOS Apps Being Proxied Through OWASP ZAP

Tags: ios, proxy, owasp, zap

Sort of a newb to OWASP ZAP/proxying apps through it, so I'm tagging OWASP in this post, but hoping someone knows how to circumvent this issue here.

On Windows 10, OWASP ZAP 2.11.1, I've generated a new certificate and installed/trusted it to my iPhone 13 Pro Max. I've setup the proxy to run over port 8081 in OWASP, and turned on the routing on the phone. I'm seeing the traffic in OWASP which is cool, however the apps aren't actually "working". For example, if I load the Instagram app, I see the traffic/sites showing up in the left pane for Instagram, but on the phone, it doesn't refresh the feed and says there's no internet connection. Some other apps just hang on the first loading screen of the app, even though I'm seeing the traffic in OWASP.

My theory here is that the traffic isn't being routed BACK to the phone, but merely being intercepted before sending it out. Am I correct in assuming this? Or what else could be happening here as I'd like the apps to work properly while I'm proxying through ZAP.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

After some digging, I'm thinking this is likely a result of "pinning", which I think can be (relatively easily) circumvented with Frida for Android apps, but maybe not so much with iOS apps. Any insights into that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at the dcos on https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/can-zap-be-used-to-test-mobile-apps/ - hopefully they will help.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the "no internet" message after following the steps above posted by Simon Bennets (https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/can-zap-be-used-to-test-mobile-apps/). Had to do extra step to trust manually installed certificate profiles as shown here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477.

Comment: I did that already too, it should be included in the first article as well. But same issue. After reviewing some of the traffic, I noticed that some of the traffic might not even be http, so I think it’s app dependent. I’ll likely start proxy interviews through wireshark to get a lower level look at the packets